# Existence of a number

Tags: c#, linq

Given an integer array

```
[1,2,3,4,1]
```

What is the easiest way to know where there exist a 1 (maybe linq)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Enumerable.Any Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx):

```
int[] yourArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1 };
bool ifExists = yourArray.Any(r => r == 1);
```

This will return true if the number exists in the array. In the above code you can replace the value `1` with your int variable, you want to compare with.

Answer (score 6):

```
bool exists = [1,2,3,4,1].Contains(1);
```

Comment: +1 for the only answer which does not require Lambda expressions

Comment: the easiest and most direct way

Answer (score 2):

Use

Any()

```
var arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

bool isExists = arr.Any(e => e == 1);
```

The isExists will return true when 1 exists on the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] x = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
bool y = x.Contains(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1 };
bool contains = array.Contains(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below code to check:

```
Array.Find(YourArray, element => element==1);
```

Hope this will help.